# Using CORS headers with CSS background-image

Tags: css, cross-domain, cors

Shortly: Is there any way to make a cross origin request for an image with the `background-image` property in CSS. I need something like the `crossOrigin` property for the img tag, but in CSS.

I am running into a problem because chrome caches the response without CORS headers, and then later, when an `<img>` tag uses the same source I get a cross-origin error because it is using the cached response that doesn't have the necessary CORS headers.

Comment: Why don't you just append a "cache buster" query parameter (like a timestamp) to the img src URL?

Comment: That's probably what I will end up doing, unless there is a better solution.

Comment: That actually won't work for me. The URL that I send the request to responds with a 302 redirect to a different URL, and it is this second URL that is being cached. In order to bust the cache I need the server to add a query paramater to the redirected URL, this is not ideal.

Comment: After doing some research I have determined that the real problem is that Amazon S3 doesn't set the "Vary: Origin" header even if it is configured to support CORS. If anyone knows how to get S3 to do that, that would also be a good answer.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

Check this API. I guess you need to configure your request to get the header to bypass the cache response..

http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/API/RESTCommonResponseHeaders.html

Comment: As I mentioned in a comment above, the url that is cached comes from a 302 redirect, so I don't have a lot of control over the actual request.