# No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present even though Header has been set

Tags: reactjs, apache, cors, axios

Let me preface this with saying that I understand how CORS work and how to not receive an error message when requesting cross site resources.

Unfortunately, for whatever reason, I am still receiving this.

The process:

1. I load my site at https://ironeko.com/
2. On Chrome, and only Chrome, I receive the following error

```
    Access to image at 'https://api.ironeko.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Group-12-3-300x272.png' from origin 'https://ironeko.com' has been blocked by CORS policy: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
```

However, all the other images from the same resource load fine upon the first page load.

This is in my `.htaccess` file:

```
<IfModule mod_setenvif.c>
  <IfModule mod_headers.c>
    <FilesMatch "\.(bmp|cur|gif|ico|jpe?g|png|svgz?|webp)$">
      SetEnvIf Origin ":" IS_CORS
      Header Set Access-Control-Allow-Origin "*" env=IS_CORS
    </FilesMatch>
  </IfModule>
</IfModule>
```

I got it from [Mozilla](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/CORS_enabled_image).

I checked my enabled modules in Apache:

```
 core_module (static)
 so_module (static)
 watchdog_module (static)
 http_module (static)
 log_config_module (static)
 logio_module (static)
 version_module (static)
 unixd_module (static)
 access_compat_module (shared)
 actions_module (shared)
 alias_module (shared)
 auth_basic_module (shared)
 authn_core_module (shared)
 authn_file_module (shared)
 authz_core_module (shared)
 authz_host_module (shared)
 authz_user_module (shared)
 autoindex_module (shared)
 deflate_module (shared)
 dir_module (shared)
 env_module (shared)
 filter_module (shared)
 headers_module (shared) <----
 http2_module (shared)
 mime_module (shared)
 mpm_event_module (shared)
 negotiation_module (shared)
 proxy_module (shared)
 proxy_fcgi_module (shared)
 proxy_http_module (shared)
 reqtimeout_module (shared)
 rewrite_module (shared)
 setenvif_module (shared) <----
 socache_shmcb_module (shared)
 ssl_module (shared)
 status_module (shared)
```

(Either way, even without the IfModule, this still doesn't work)

EDIT: I previously thought the problem was caused by my normal image request. But I am making a secondary request using [react-palette](https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-palette). This is what I believe is actually causing the CORS error.

```
function returnImageColor(src) {
  const { data, loading, error } = usePalette(src);
  return data;
}
```

What is going on here? Why is this just happening with Chrome? Is there a mistake in the CORS header?

Comment: Is this by any chance a new site? Have the DNS records been recently updated or a server has been changed at the hosting company? If so, it could be that the DNS records changes have not completely propagated to all DNS servers, and on occasion the `api.ironeko.com` domain is being resolved to an outdated server IP which does not return any CORS headers.

Comment: It's been online for maybe three months? I haven't touched the DNS (except for DKIM and SPF records) for a long time. The VPS has received no significant changes if not maybe a new virtual host for a separate site has been added.

Comment: Also I tested in a incognito instance of chrome, this actually seems to happen with every image, will update the OP.

Comment: I understand. This is only an educated guess, since this issue seems to occur intermittently. In fact, for me it only happened once, the very first time I've accessed the site with all images (without scrolling), but has not happened since. I cannot reproduce it in incognito either. When it happens, I suggest you look in the network tab of the developers tools and check to what "Remote Address" the requests are being resolved.

Comment: Also look at this issue: [Using CORS headers with CSS background-image](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21638606/using-cors-headers-with-css-background-image)

Comment: Remote Address resolves to 165.227.170.254:443, which is my VPS. Funnily enough for some images I'll get a CORS error even though they're loading correctly and even though they show the correct headers on the Network tab.

Comment: What's the HTTP status code of the response? You can use the Network pane in browser devtools to check. Is it a 4xx or 5xx error rather than a 200 OK success response?

Comment: @sideshowbarker For the images that load, even though I still get the error, the response comes up as 200.

Comment: Okay I think I understand a bit better what's happening. I am actually making a secondary request using react-palette (https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-palette) to figure out the image's primary color. This is what seems to be responding with an error, not the normal image loading.

Comment: When I load https://ironeko.com/ now, I can’t reproduce this. I see no COR errors getting logged — not in Chrome, Firefox, or Safari. But just a minute ago, when I first loaded it in Chrome, I did see CORS errors logged to the devtools console. Reloading now though, I see none.

Comment: `curl -i -H "Origin: https://example.com" https://api.ironeko.com/wp-content/uploads/2019/08/Group-12-3-300x272.png` shows `Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *`

Comment: I can reproduce the error every time with Chrome. What would that curl mean? That the headers didn't update?

Comment: That curl output means that the server is actually sending the headers over the wire. So it could just be a caching problem I guess